# Calling trait function for each struct in Vec<Obj>

Tags: rust

I'm confused about how to call a trait function for each `Obj` in a `Vec`.

```
pub async fn get_assets(document: Document) -> StdResult<u16> {
    document
        .components
        .iter()
        .for_each(|c| c.snippets.iter().for_each(|snip| snip::download()));
    Ok(200) // just for testing
}
```

This function returns this compiler error:

```
error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `snip`
   --> src/api.rs:220:57
    |
220 |         .for_each(|c| c.snippets.iter().for_each(|snip| snip::download()));
    |                                                         ^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `snip`
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: You've used the `::` (path separator) instead of `.`. If you want to do a fully qualified call, you can do it like `crate::module::download(&snip)`.

Comment: Ah, thank-you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FZs mentioned, my issue was that I used `::` (the path separator) instead of `.`.

Functioning code:

```
pub async fn get_assets(document: Document) -> StdResult<u16> {
    document
        .components
        .iter()
        .for_each(|c| c.snippets.iter().for_each(|snip| snip.download()));
    Ok(200) // just for testing
}
```